# Helm Hook not triggered

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm

Context: Kubenete 1.0.3, Helm 2.8.2

Helm Hook: pre-install 
  weight: 0
  delete-policy: before-hook-creation

Helm command: helm upgrade --install -n namespace

Problem description: 
  The hook block is well rendered when running with --dry-run mode. But after installing (without dry-run), no hook job is triggered.

Check the job using command kubectl get jobs -n namespace.

Comment: Did you actually install or upgrade your deployment? If upgrade - the hook will not be created.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it guides me to the right path. The hook should be pre-upgrade!

Comment: @X.J Could you please add this as an answer, so others who might have the same problem can find this easier?

Answer (score -2):

Hook is a mechanism introduced in HELM to intervence at certain points in release life cycle. 
Hooks can be definied in few ways via special annotations in metadata section, i.e. "pre-install", "post-install", "pre-upgrade" etc. Example of the hook:

```
apiVersion: ...
kind: ....
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
```

Full list of Hooks can be found [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md). In addition there can be used more than one hook.

In this case "pre-upgrade" option resolved the issue which was 
"**Executes on an upgrade request after templates are rendered, but before any resources are loaded into Kubernetes (e.g. before a Kubernetes apply operation).**"